# iOS Tutorials for Xcode 3.2.6

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode3.2

Just trying to learn how to do iOS as best I *can* with my current computer (MacBook 2,1; OS X 10.6.8).

I've done all the "How to Make and iPhone App" tutorials from [http://mobileorchard.com/author
/oscar/](http://mobileorchard.com/author/oscar/) but I'm looking for more! If anyone has any good tutorials for me (or anyone else

stuck in the "Stone Age"), I'd appreciate it!

Comment: "Just trying to learn how to do iOS as best I can" - first, then forget Xcode.

Comment: @H2CO3 "then forget Xcode", why?  I ask because I myself i'm in the process of learning so i'm curious about it.

Comment: @fmendez Because if you start using an IDE and start learning from tutorials that don't even mention the world/life outside the IDE, you'll quickly pick up seriously bad programming practices, you'll confuse the language (Objective-C) with the OS (iOS) with the device (iPhone, iPad) with the IDE (Xcode) with the APIs you're using (Cocoa Touch), etc. Bitter own experience - **a lot** of beginners have the same problem here on SO, *every single day.*

Comment: @H2CO3 Ohh you mean that, completely agree (i'm having some of that confusion myself right now). Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @fmendez In that spirit, I advise you to start by getting your hands off iOS, firstly. Start by learning pure C. Master C. Only then look into Objective-C. For all this, you won't even need Xcode. Learn to use and to invoke the compiler from the command line. Familiarize yourself with the error messages it prints - google a lot. Compile with all warnings enabled and almost always fix all warnings. Choose a coding style and **use it,** and use it *consistently* in order not to make other programmers have the urge to vomit seeing your code. Etc., etc., etc.

Comment: yeah, I'm not a beginner in terms of programming, just trying to learn the iOS ecosystem...but I appreciate the input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though learning iOs as best as you can will probably prove not to be enough in the long term (at least not if you want to get serious about it: mobile developing is a pretty fast moving target...), there are still a couple of things you can do to leverage the system you own:

**Read the programming guides by Apple**

Even though both Apple and Google have the annoying habit of replacing the old documentation with the new one without leaving traces of the previous revisions, you can still sift it and separate what's relevant only for the latest versions of iOs and what still applies for Xcode 3.2.6.

For instance the "View Controller Programming Guide":

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457

has a lot of stuff about Storyboards you can't use, but the basics of VC programming are still there.

It approach will require you a lot of effort, and long sessions of trial and error, but you will definitely find all the info you need.

**Search internet for old tutorials**

Even though Apple likes to wipe out it's own history, doesn't mean most blogger and contributors in internet will.

Google has a feature that allows you to search a page created between two dates of your choice: use it to find tutorials, guides and code created in the time interval when your version of XCode was on the market.

Comment: That link is a nice push in the right direction. I was thinking the Developer docs were the best place to go, but was seeing if anyone had anything. Thanks for the input.